# Interpolating two spherical coordinates (theta, phi)

Tags: spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry

I have two points on a unit sphere, given as tuples $(\theta, \phi)$. I need an efficient way to interpolate them, for example given $t$ between zero and one, to generate a point that lies (on the unit sphere) between the two points, where $t = 0$ would give the first point, $t = 1$ would give the second point, and $t = 0.5$ would give a point that is exactly in the middle.

I read about [Slerp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp), but I don't know how to apply the quaternions math to the spherical coordinates.

(If the two points are antipodal, let the result be random)

It seems to be very similar to [this question/answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383711/parametric-equation-for-great-circle#384719), only that I use spherical coordinates instead of latitude/longitude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple algorithm

1. Define the angles $(\theta_1,\phi_2)$ and $(\theta_2,\phi_1)$
2. Transform these into cartesian vectors ${\bf x}_1$ and ${\bf x}_2$ using

\begin{eqnarray}
x &=& \sin\theta\cos\phi \\
y &=& \sin\theta\sin\phi \\
z &=& \cos\theta\tag{1}
\end{eqnarray}

3. Build the vector

$$
{\bf k} = \frac{{\bf x}_1 \times {\bf x}_2}{|{\bf x}_1 \times {\bf x}_2|} \tag{2}
$$

This is a vector perpendicular to the plane spanned by ${\bf x}_1$ and ${\bf x}_2$

4. Calculate the angle between ${\bf x}_1$ and ${\bf x}_2$

$$
\theta = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{{\bf x}_1 \cdot {\bf x}_2}{|{\bf x}_1||{\bf x}_2|}\right) \tag{3}
$$

5. For $\psi$ in the range $0$ to $\theta$ with steps $\Delta\theta$ calculate the [vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula)

$$
{\displaystyle \mathbf {x}_\psi =\mathbf {x}_1 \cos \psi +(\mathbf {k} \times \mathbf {x}_1 )\sin \psi +\mathbf {k} ~(\mathbf {k} \cdot \mathbf {x}_1 )(1-\cos \psi )} \tag{4}
$$

6. The set of vectors $\{{\bf x}_\psi\}_\psi$ are uniformly spaced, if you want the angles associated with each point just use the inverse transformation of (1)

[image]

This is an example using $(\theta_1,\phi_1) = (0.4, 1.0)$, $(\theta_2,\phi_2) = (2.0, 1.6)$ and $\Delta \theta = 0.1$

Comment: "the angle between x1 and x2" - that is the central angle, correct? (because I have that one already precalculated directly from the spherical coordinates as $\cos^{-1}{(\cos{\theta_1}\cos{\theta_2}  + \sin{\theta_1}\sin{\theta_2}\cos{(\phi_1 - \phi_2}))}$

Comment: Well, it is the same thing, since $|{\bf x}_1| = |{\bf x}_2| = 1$ then $$\cos\theta = {\bf x}_1 \cdot {\bf x}_2 = (\sin\theta_1 \cos\phi_1)(\sin\theta_2 \cos\phi_2) + (\sin\theta_1 \cos\sin \phi_1)(\sin\theta_1 \cos\sin \phi_2) + (\cos\theta_1)(\cos\theta_2) = \sin\theta_1 \sin\theta_2 (\cos\phi_1\cos\phi_2 + \sin \theta_1 \sin \theta_2) + \cos\theta_1 \cos\theta_2 = \sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2\cos(\phi_1 - \phi_2) + \cos\theta_1 \cos\theta_2 $$

Answer (score 0):

I simply did
sin(1-t)*P1 + sin(t)*P2 for t in range [0, 1]

when P1 and P2 are in cartesian coordinates. I have no idea why it works but it works..