# Sphere arch parameterization

Tags: geometry, spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry

I have an engineering problem that I can't get right.

I have a unit vector in point A and a unit vector in point B. I know that the two points are connected by a spherical arch. That is, they both lie on the same sphere, and the two unit vectors both point along this sphere (tangential to the sphere). I also know the arch length between the two points, but I am not given the actual positions of the points (need to set a reference).

I need a parameterization in one variable f(t) of the curve between the two points. [Figure: Parametrize curve along sphere from Q to P](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLTPp.png)

From what I figure, it should be defined by the central angle between the points (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) and the radius R of the sphere, which I have both found. But **I can't figure out how to make a parameterization f(t) = [x(t), y(t), z(t)].**

**EDIT:**
Note that I am not given the positions A and B, only the unit vector in these points which is assumed to point tangential to the sphere and the arch length between them. This is a real life problem, and the apparatus gives direction of motion at t_0 and direction of motion at t_1 and the distance travelled. It is assumed to travel in spherical motions with a large R (I can adjust for the R later). So I can naturally set the position of A to (0,0,0), but I am not given the position of B.

All help is appreciated:) Kind regards,
Fredrik

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Two questions 1) Are your arcs **spherical arcs** (verifying shortest distance between two points) i.e., portions of great circles ? 2) I don't understand the fact that the spherical coordinates of your points P **and** Q are **unknown**. Don't you mean "general" instead of "unknown". Can we call them $(R,\theta_k,\phi_k)$ $k=0,1$ ?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2799250/305862

Answer (score 2):

**Original answer, with some extra explanations** As was pointed out in the comments, you should specify whether the arcs are parts of great circles. The link in your questions discusses the great-circle distance, hence I assume this is indeed what you mean.

**A general parametrization of a circle.**
A general parametrization of a (full) circle of radius $R$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, with the origin as a center, is
$$
 f : [0, 2\pi] \to \mathbb{R}^3 : t \mapsto R\cos t\, u + R\sin t\, v, \tag{1}
$$
where $u$ and $v$ are two orthonormal vectors.
Note that $f(0)=u$ and $f(\pi/2)$. You can also verify that $f$ is indeed
a circle:
$$
\begin{align}
 \|f(t)\|^2 &= R^2 \cos^2 t (u\cdot u)+ R^2 \sin^2 t (v\cdot v)- 2 R^2 \cos t \sin t  (u \cdot v) \\
& = R^2.
\end{align}
$$

**Where does the expression come from?**
This expression is obtained performing a suitable rotation of the parametrization of the "standard circle":
$$
(R\cos t, R\sin t, 0) = R\cos t\, \mathbf{e}_1 + R\sin t\, \mathbf{e}_2. \tag{2}
$$
We have just replace the $\mathbf{e}_i$ by two other vectors.

**What do we need to do?**
We need to look for two orthonormal vectors $u$ and $v$ and plug these into expression $(1)$. (Using expression $(2)$ and calculating a suitable rotation in $\mathbb{R}^3$ involves more work.)

If we are given two unit vectors $A$ and $B$ that determine the two *positions* on the sphere: we are going to look for a vector $C$ such that

- $C$ is a unit vector
- $C$ lies in the plane spanned by $A$ and $B$ (we assume they span a plane).
- $C$ is orthogonal to $A$.

Let $\theta = d/R$ be the angle from $A$ to $B$.
Then $C$ becomes
$$
     C = \frac{B - (B\cdot A) A}{\|B - (B\cdot A)A\|} = \frac{B - \cos \theta A}{\sin\theta}.
$$

The parametrization then becomes
$$
 f : [0,\theta] \to \mathbb{R}^3 : t \mapsto R\cos t\, A + R\sin t\, C,
$$

As an exercise, you can verify that $f(\theta) = B$.

**Addendum: answer if $A$ and $B$ describe tangent vectors**
After my first answer, the OP clarified that $A$ and $B$ are not *positions*, but they are the (unit) *directions* of the spherical arc.

We can still use expression $(1)$. When we derive $(1)$, we get that
the speed unit vector at $t$ is $-\sin t u + \cos t v$. Evaluating  $t_0$ and $t_1$ gives
$$
\begin{align*}
  - \sin t_0 u + \cos t_0 v &= A,\\
  - \sin t_1 u + \cos t_1 v &= B. 
\end{align*}
$$
Solving this system (together with $\|u\|=1$, $\|v\|=1$ and $u\cdot v = 0$),  give $u$ and $v$.

Alternatively, since the movement is circular, $A$ and $B$ lie in the plane of movement. Hence the vector $A\times B$ is  normal to the plane that contains the arc.
So taking the cross product of $A$ and $B$ with $A\times B/\|A\times B\|$, should give you (up to a minus sign) the position vectors $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Great thank you! Can I ask how you derived the result? I understand if writing it all out is tedious, but maybe you could explain your starting point to find it? I guess there should be possible to parameterize the path element dS along the trajectory, but I can't remember how:)

Kind regards,
Fredrik

Comment: I made an edit that explains what information is available:)

Comment: @Fredrik I gave an extra explanation and some intuition to the original answer. If I understand your edit well, then $A$ and $B$ are _not_ positions, but they are unit vectors tangent to the sphere (they are the unit directions of the spherical arc). In this case, the answer of course changes. I made an addendum for this. I did my best to explain _everything_. I hope it is helpful.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful!