Which function represents the lat/long intersection of a plane that intersects a sphere at its center?
Imagine a unit sphere and a plane cutting through the centre of the sphere. If you draw the intersection in latitude/longitude coordinates, you will get a function that looks close to a sine function. If the angle of inclination of the plane is small, it looks more like a sin function than if the angle of inclination is close to 90°. I'm interested in which function it is.
So suppose we have two points $p_0, p_1 \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with a range $[-\pi, \pi)$ for the first component and a range $[-\pi / 2, \pi /2]$ for the second component. These two points represent points on the surface of the sphere as longitude and latitude in radians.
With these two points and the centre of the sphere, the cutting plane is well defined.
Let us assume that $p_0 \neq p_1$ and also that the first components of $p_0$ and $p_1$ are different. So we don't have a strict vertical plane.
How do you get the intersection function to have just the two points $p_0$ and $p_1$ in longitude latitude coordinates?

FWIW, if you replace the sphere with a right circular cylinder—in other words, unroll the cylinder and its intersection with a slicing plane not parallel to its axis—the result (in Cartesian coordinatesj is a sine wave.

Perhaps this question is relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383711/parametric-equation-for-great-circle

@PaulSinclair very nice! I was looking for that! if you write this as an answer, then I confirm it. Thanks a lot!

Since I just looked the formula up, I hadn't considered it. But it does help the site to have answered questions, so I will.

The intersection of a sphere with a plane through its center is called a "great circle" of the sphere. So what you are after is the latitude of a great circle as a function of longitude. You can find a formula for it here. As "lat1, lon1,lat2, lon2" are just constants specifying two points on the great circle, the curve can be expressed more succinctly as
$$\phi =\arctan(A\sin(θ−θ_0))$$
where

$\phi$ = latitude,
$\theta$ = longitude,
$A,\theta_0$ are constants.

The curve looks like a sine curve with its peaks and valleys flattened a bit.
$\theta_0$ just moves the curve right or left. $A$ controls its height, though non-linearly. When $A \le 1$, the flattening from a true sinusoid is hardly noticible, but when $A$ gets large, it becomes severe.
