# Relation between longitude, latitude and degrees from a compass?

Tags: trigonometry

I have two points on a map, each with known latitude and longitude. I also have a compass on my iPhone which shows the degrees. Is there any relation between these three?

Say I'm in point 1 and I want to go to point 2. Do the degrees show me anything regarding the correct direction? For example, if my compass shows 30 degrees, than I know I'm going forward to point 2. How can I calculate that? Please help!

Comment: This is about Rhumb lines. You can have a look in Wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhumb_line.

Comment: Thank you! I could find a solution there.

Comment: The exact answer depends on further details about what kind of information you want. Did you select magnetic or true compass directions on your iPhone? Do you want a path such that point 2 is always in the same direction, or do you want the shortest path from point 1 to point 2? Do you want to take into account the fact that the Earth's radius is larger at the equator than at the poles, or are formulas that assume the Earth is a sphere good enough?

Comment: The point of all those requests for detail is not to make the problem more complicated, but to find out how complicated you need it to be. For a good approximation (for many purposes) at any distance you can look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45293/how-to-get-the-cardinal-direction-from-one-location-to-another, but if the two points are only a few kilometers apart you can use a much simpler formula.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking interest! The idea is like this: say I'm blind, like literally blind. I just want to point the top of my iPhone in a direction, and if that is the direction to my house, the iPhone vibrates, so I know I'm heading the right way.

Comment: The iPhone gives me the degrees to True North, and I know the latitude, longitude of my current location and the location of my house

Comment: The distances between home and current location should be quite small comparative to Earth's size. Indeed, they are only a few miles apart.